# How to bend a mesh evenly?

Tags: modifiers

I am working on the mesh that I'm trying to bend 250 degrees around itself.

[image: front view]

[image: top view]

I tried using simple deform modifier but as a result I keep on getting following result.

[image: top view after applying the bend]

What should I do in order to 'block' or make all the lines follow the bend so that when looking from the top view none of the line would surpass?

Comment: Add a sub div modifier. Let me know how it works

Comment: Or select the interior edges and subdivide them, subdiv modifier might give you some undesirable geometry

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers.  Finally the problem was in the basic construction of the mesh.  I added the loop cuts to each of the lines and now I can bend it easily using the Simple deform modifier.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in the construction of the mesh. I added loop cuts to each of the lines and then bended it using the simple deform modifier.

[image: Final view from the front]

Final result

[image: Final view from the top]